# Delphi 2009 and Synapse - tested and ready for Unicode support?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, ararat-synapse

Is Synapse ready for a Delphi 2009 production applications?  Their website doesn't look like it's been updated in a while:  http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php   Is the project dead?

Comment: As of September 2010, the latest stable release is 39 and still does not appear to be compatible with Delphi 2009 (*heaps* of compiler warnings about implicit string conversion with data loss.) No good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using the latest version from the SVN repository without any problems in a commercial application compiled with Delphi 2009.

Comment: Good to hear!  Thanks.  I saw just a few changes in the SVN and was wondering if he finished full support yet.

Answer (score 1):

The D2009 support not released but you can download directly from the [svn repository](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4A0D26D2-46D3-4747-90F7-7FCD054F1CE0%40emailaya.com&forum_name=synalist-public), if you browse the code there, you will see there are changes for D2009 compatibility

http://synalist.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/synalist/trunk/

Comment: Do you know if the changes are complete?  There were just a few marked as D2009 updates.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the synapse author suggest to download it from the svn, look at the first link "svn repository" to see his reply